# Use custom timestamp instead of now() in sub_date

Tags: mysql

When I use:

```
timestamp > UNIX_TIMESTAMP(DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 30 day))
```

it works, but I want to use custom timestamp date instead of NOW()

```
timestamp > UNIX_TIMESTAMP(DATE_SUB(date('Y-m-d H:i:s', 1430595837), INTERVAL 30 day))
```

But it doesn't work properly.

How can I place custom date there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The date that you have is not in the 'Y-m-d H:i:s' format. Those are seconds since epoch.

```
timestamp > UNIX_TIMESTAMP(DATE_SUB(FROM_UNIXTIME(1430595837), INTERVAL 30 day))
```

Comment: The problem here is how to limit to just 1 day. timestamp > UNIX_TIMESTAMP(DATE_SUB(FROM_UNIXTIME('1430595837'), interval 1 day) AND timestamp < UNIX_TIMESTAMP(DATE_SUB(FROM_UNIXTIME('1430595837+86400'), interval 1 day)) but it doesn't limit

Comment: Are you looking for all timestamps for the day around this specific timestamp? You would use this in your comparisons : `timestamp >= UNIX_TIMESTAMP(DATE_FORMAT(FROM_UNIXTIME('1430595837'),"%Y-%m-%d 00:00:00"))
AND timestamp <= UNIX_TIMESTAMP(DATE_FORMAT(FROM_UNIXTIME('1430595837'),"%Y-%m-%d 23:59:59"))`

Answer (score 3):

You need to use `from_unixtime` function

```
mysql> select UNIX_TIMESTAMP(DATE_SUB(from_unixtime('1430595837'), interval 30 day)) as a ;
+------------+
| a          |
+------------+
| 1428003837 |
+------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

so it becomes

```
timestamp > UNIX_TIMESTAMP(DATE_SUB(from_unixtime('1430595837'), interval 30 day))
```

Comment: Not working properly :( it get all records. If I use interval 1 day it get records from last week too

Comment: provide some sample data so that it could be validated, the answer I provided is the correct usage of timestamp value into the question.

Comment: sorry, my fault. Working properly!

Comment: One more thing: SELECT id_network,id_site,id_adunit,timestamp FROM tmp_stats WHERE id_network = 4 AND timestamp > UNIX_TIMESTAMP(DATE_SUB(from_unixtime('1431077699'), interval 1 day)) returns 5000 rows. And SELECT id_network,id_site,id_adunit,timestamp FROM tmp_stats WHERE id_network = 4 AND timestamp > 1431007699 + 86400 returns 2500

Comment: You are adding the date_sub into a timestamp so you will get data which are having timestamp value greater than  given timestamp minus i day or 30 day whichever you provide. So you need to check the records and condition based on which data should be retured.

Answer (score 0):

```
timestamp > UNIX_TIMESTAMP(DATE_SUB(FROM_UNIXTIME(1430595837), interval 1 day))
```

It returns all records, and if I change 1430595837 to 11 or any other number, it returns all records.

line code:

```
        $select_stats_network = $this->db->prepare("SELECT id_network,id_site,id_adunit,timestamp FROM tmp_stats WHERE id_network = (SELECT id_network FROM tmp_stats ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT 1) AND timestamp > UNIX_TIMESTAMP(DATE_SUB(FROM_UNIXTIME(1430595837), interval 1 day))");
```